# prepDocuments Function in R gives invalid times error

Tags: r, topic-modeling

So I created a Structrural Topic Model (https://rdrr.io/cran/stm/), a propabilistic model of text classification which incorporates metadata.
Now I want to run a permutation test (https://rdrr.io/cran/stm/man/plot.STMpermute.html) for which I used the suggested example:

```
`temp<-textProcessor(documents=gadarian$open.ended.response,metadata=gadarian)
out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta)
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
set.seed(02138)
mod.out <- stm(documents, vocab, 3, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
summary(mod.out)
prep <- estimateEffect(1:3 ~ treatment + s(pid_rep), mod.out, meta)
plot(prep, "treatment", model=mod.out,
     method="difference",cov.value1=1,cov.value2=0)
test <- permutationTest(formula=~ treatment + s(pid_rep), stmobj=mod.out, 
                        treatment="treatment", nruns=25, documents=documents,
                        vocab=vocab,data=meta, stmverbose=FALSE)
plot(test,2, xlab="Effect", ylab="Model Index", main="Topic 2 Placebo Test")`
```

I applied this to the elements of my own dataframe - please correct me here if i did target the wrong element, maybe - I am guessing the metadata parameter is wrong?)

```
`temp <-textProcessor(documents=daten_dfm_fit_CryptoCombined$documents,metadata=daten_dfm_fit_CryptoCombined$meta)
out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta)
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
mod.out <- stm(documents, vocab, 3, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
summary(mod.out)
prep <- estimateEffect(1:3 ~ treatment + s(pid_rep), mod.out, meta)
plot(prep, "treatment", model=mod.outTest,
     method="difference",cov.value1=1,cov.value2=0)
permTestObj <- permutationTest(formula=~ treatment + s(pid_rep), stmobj=mod.out, 
                               treatment="treatment", nruns=100, documents=documents,
                               vocab=vocab,data=meta, stmverbose=FALSE)
plot(permTestObj,2, xlab="Effect", ylab="Model Index", main="Topic 2 Placebo Test")`
```

After the first line, the moment it tries to create the object "out" I get this error message

```
`> out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta):
Error in rep(1:length(documents), times = VsubD) : 
  invalid 'times' argument`
```

Now I am confused because:
a) I thought i am using prepDoc, which is not a repfunction? I mean i did not state any times of reps?
Therefore I dont know how
(https://www.statology.org/r-error-rep-invalid-times-argument/) should help.

b) Could any property of the dfms I target be wrong? Maybe if they contain empty rows?

c) Is it because i did target the wrong components all together?

Please tell me in case I have to provide the full code
Thank you for your time.

I tried to run it and expected it to work without interrruptions
I researched the problem and tried to clean the dfms via the textProcessor or prepDocuments variables but none of them seemed to offer a drop empty entries feature

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error with prepDocument. Did you find a solution?

Comment: no sry not yet, I also tried chatGPT which told me that the number of documents need to be the same nr than the meta data - i tested that and they are the same so now i have no clue what the problem is:

Comment: https://chat.openai.com/c/32f02b9c-59e3-4769-b85f-44d839f229b4